# What is the fastest Traversable instance in the land

Tags: arrays, performance, haskell

I am using the ad library http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad and I am looking for the fastest traversable to pass to its various functions.

Ideally it would be a data structure that uses a contiguous array of memory so I can pass it of to numeric solver in C++ world.

What's my best bet?

Comment: I don't believe there are any structures that both implement `Traversable` and exist as a memory array that can be passed directly to C/C++.

Comment: Could one create a GHC plugin that would switch the representation somehow, or is that too unsafe and difficult to be considered feasible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a data structure that uses a contiguous array of memory so I can pass it of to numeric solver in C++ world.

Use a Storable instance of the [unboxed Vector type.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html)

The 'Storable' constraint -- being able to be passed to C -- restricts your available data types a lot. Vectors support very fast [bulk operations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html#g:20). Another alternative would be Repa arrays.

However, you will be limited as the `ad` package requires Functor and Traversable, but they're provided only for completeness - and actually serialize to lists to get the traversable instance. Traversable and Storable won't ever intermix, since Storable is class-limited to certain unboxed types.

Comment: My guess is if Vector is converting to and from lists, it might be faster to use lists in some instances.

Comment: @Jonathan Fischoff it is only a convenient way to I/O data from/to vector infrastructure. Normally high-performance vectors precessing shouldn't deal with lists at all.

Comment: @leventov I agree, If I could choose to use a AD package that played nice with Vector, but since that is not the case its not clear using Vectors traversable will be better than just using a list ... or is it?

Answer (score 2):

`instance Traversable (Data.Functor.Constant a)`

(sorry!)